# SharePoint Search 2010 Full crawl

Tags: enterprise-search

I have seem organization run full crawl over the weekend and I have a simple question. Is there any benefits of running full crawl on a scheduled basis, although we have an incremental crawl?

I am aware that full crawl needs to be run for the following scenarios:
-New Content source
-New File Types
-New Managed properties
-New crawl rules
-Index Corruption

Does MS has any best practices on whether to run full crawl on a scheduled basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSFT recommend that you run full crawls less frequently than incremental crawls.

**Here are the reason when you need to run full crawl.**

- software update or service pack was installed on servers in the farm
- SharePoint Server 2010 Search service application administrator added a new managed property
- You want to resolve consecutive incremental crawl failures
- Crawl rules have been added, deleted, or modified.
- You want to repair a corrupted index.
- The Search service application administrator has created one or more server name mappings
- The credentials for the user account that is assigned to the default content access account or a crawl rule have changed.

**SharePoint Perform full crawl even you requested Incremental in few situations.**

- A search administrator stopped the previous crawl.
- A content database was restored, or a farm administrator has detached and reattached a content database.
- A full crawl of the site has never been done from this Search service application
- The change log does not contain entries for the addresses that are being crawled. Without entries in the change log for the items being crawled, incremental crawls cannot occur.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262926(v=office.14).aspx#section1

Comment: Do we need to run Full crawl if Database CU patch installed?

Comment: Yes, you have to run the full crawl "A software update or service pack was installed on servers in the farm"https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262926.aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-BQ5pHQr3EvsuD9tcbvr8Hg&tduid=(1462ea5e4aab5de511def1657a0059c7)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-BQ5pHQr3EvsuD9tcbvr8Hg)()